# TeamCity gitlab integration

Tags: teamcity, gitlab

AFAIK there are not official TeamCity and Gitlab integration plugins, but is there any unofficial project doing this? I need to dynamically build merge requests created on Gitlab on TeamCity and provide feedback of the build status on merge request section.
Anybody have achieved this? Is there any alternative using other CI server?

Comment: You can create a feature request for this on `feedback.gitlab.com`

Comment: what kind of feedback where you looking for?

Comment: Please consider voting for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-41219

Comment: I believe this question contains the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36172292/show-in-gitlab-teamcity-builds-status

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out Team Citys rather extensive REST API?https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/REST+API

Maybe you can find what you're looking for there?